# Vagrant up does not work with VMWare provider

Tags: vagrant, vmware, setuid

I'm using Vagrant on the latest Linux Mint. It works fine with VirtualBox, however with VMWare it fails with this error: `sudo helper setuid-wrapper must run as root.`

The very few discussions about this issue I found on the net suggested to symlink `~/.vagrant.d` to an not encrypted disk. This is what I tried, but unfortunately without any success at all. I also created symlinks for `~/vmware` and  `~/.vmware`, but again without success.

Has anyone come across this error and found a solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you share your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: There's nothing special to it really. The error happens with every Vagrantfile and every box.

Comment: so any box with the VMWare provider ? do you have any specific provisioning ? I am running all my Vmx against VMWare and never seen anything like this

Comment: No special provisioning, just a clean out of the box Vagrantfile, if you will. It even happens if I create a new box with Packer and vagrant init that box and don't change anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue today (Vagrant 1.9.3/Ubuntu 17.04/VMWare Workstation 12.5.5) if using an encrypted homedir.  For me, the easiest solution was just to move the vagrant directory onto a non-encrypted filesystem as the OP suggested:

```
sudo mkdir /vagrant
sudo mv ~/.vagrant.d/ /vagrant/
ln -s /vagrant/.vagrant.d/ ~/.vagrant.d
```

Running in debug mode I can see the command its trying to run as root exists within the directory I moved:

```
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/home/geoff/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-vmware-workstation-4.0.18/bin/vagrant_vmware_desktop_sudo_helper_wrapper_linux_amd64", "prune-forwarded-ports", "/tmp/vagrant-sudo-helper20170422-15385-brgg1q"]
```

And sure enough after `vagrant up` the VM now runs.  Putting everything under `/vagrant` like this is a bit of a bodge and you would need to figure out something more elegant if you have more then one user, perhaps `/vagrant/$USER`.  The directory I chose isn't Linux FHS compliant either but who cares ;-)

I wish this worked out the box but perhaps this will help someone